# Meteor domutils error

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor application that starts to be quite large. I have still quite important problems to debug my application for exemple I have a error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeType' of null domutils.js?52c3c7ff9e0acd52ac427a8f103760e222ba2722:295
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_spark_bY6hxpJRdJcb2nynQ' of null
```

I cannot find the source of the error.

Comment: Are you using some kind of external JQuery library that manipulates the html?

Comment: Yes I do. I use Jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  For me it occurred when I clicked a link which caused a new template to load.  When I added:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

as shown below, the error was corrected.

```
Template.define_blocks.events({
    'click #tb_yes': function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```